# Matplotlib: does slicing plt.imshow() correspond to slicing the source numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib

Say you have the following `numpy.array`:

```
a=numpy.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]])
```

which you plot with

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
b=plt.imshow(a)
```

[image]

**My question**: if you "slice" the image like this

```
b=plt.imshow(a)
plt.xlim(0.5,2.5)
plt.ylim(0.5,2.5)
```

do the plotted values correspond to

```
a[1:3,1:3]?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each row and column will span or have a width 1.0. The rows of the matrix span the x axis, and the columns of the matrix span the y axis. If we start by looking at the rows in the matrix, the first entry will be centered at 0.0, the next at 1.0, and so on. Same for columns. Because the width is 1.0, the first entry could be said to go from -0.5 to 0.5, then the next from 0.5 to 1.5. Because of the interpolation, it will actually be a weighting of the neighbor values of the matrix.

If we set the plot limits like this:

```
plt.xlim(1,2)
plt.ylim(1,2)
```

we would select the area between entry 2 and 3 (1 indexed) in the rows and columns. But these values are *in between* the values of the matrix.

The selection `a[1:3,1:3]` would be more like:

```
plt.xlim(0.5, 2.5)
plt.ylim(0.5, 2.5)
```

Comment: So, essentially, your answer is "yes", but I need to change the `limits` to account for the exact positions of the values. Is that so? Is your answer yes?

Comment: Essentially "yes" - the limits have to correspond :)

Comment: Isn't there a way to turn of interpolation?

Comment: Yes, it can be done with `plt.imshow(a,  interpolation='none')`.